# Laravel 5: numeric values output as integers or string in different systems?

Tags: laravel-5, casting

I'm running LVL 5.2.45 on two systems:

- OSX 10.11.6, with PHP 7.0.13 (homebrew)
- Ubuntu 14.04.5, with PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20

I am getting two different outputs from this code (eg. in Tinker):

```
App\Product::where('name', 'big brown bag')->get();
```

On OSX it outputs:

```
 App\Product {#744
 id: 54,
 name: "Big Brown Bag",
 category_id: 3,
 company_id: 1,
}
```

On Ubuntu:

```
 App\Product {#744
 id: 54,
 name: "Big Brown Bag",
 category_id: "3",
 company_id: "1",
}
```

Notice the double quotes around the ids in the Ubuntu output. The same outputs in a JSON.

How could I normalize this? Specifically, how could I force it to output the ids as integers?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your case was quite interesting to me I spent some time searching for you a possible answer. Frameworks like Laravel use the PDO for working with different kind of DBMS and this kind of approach requires specific drivers.

I think that the problem is because of the php5-mysql library that is involved in the interaction with your MySQL database: this lib does NOT convert the number-type columns to a type number, leaving the Eloquent ORM with a string-type in return.

**A possible solution** is to replace the php5-mysql library with php5-mysqlnd (sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd). In fact the mysqlnd library returns a number type value instead of an insignificant string. As you're working with two different kind of PHP versions on your environments, I'm quite sure that it's just a matter of different libraries (and a different way of treating the value data type).

A quicker but **dirt** solution is to define the $casts protected property as an array where the key is the column and the value is the type you want that value to be casted. In example:

```
protected $casts = ['category_id' => 'integer']
```

[This paragraph of the Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) will be helpful to those are interested in this kind of approach

Anyway, this kind of problems should be avoided using a virtual machine packed for the dev team. Laravel offers an awesome virtual environment to use (I'm sure you've already heard of Homestead) that you can even use for other web-based applications, frameworks and CMS.

Comment: Thank you for the time and the completeness of explaination.